# Cannot See Validation Rules

Tags: validation, validation-rule, customsetting, tooling-api, workbench

My boss has asked that we modify all validation rules in our org. We’re creating a custom setting that will allow admins to bypass all validation rules (validation rules will not apply to admins in our org). In order to do this, I believe you have to manually add the custom setting to your validation rule. I’ve queried in Workbench and found the names of every validation rule in our org. When I go to settings>object manager I cannot see the validation rule. My boss found the same when querying Tooling API. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you need to navigate *to the object the rules are on*, at which point you will see `Validation Rules` as one of your view options, along with `Details`, `Fields & Relationships`, etc.

[image: Object Setup]

Second important note, a `Custom Setting` is *not* best practice for this requirement. You should instead use a **`Custom Permission`** which you can add to any `Profile` or `Permission Set` you wish to be exempt.